# how to find the detail of auctex startup?

Tags: auctex

when i open a .tex files, i always see

```
Applying style hooks...done
Sorting environment...done
Removing duplicates...done
```

yes, i use

```
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
```

in `.emacs`

now, i want to know:

```
which "duplicates" found and removed ?
which "style hooks" applied ?
which "enviroment" sorted ?
```

Answer (score 2):

AUCTeX doesn't make a detailed log. If you want to see what it does, you'll have to explore the variables used by the corresponding function, or run it in a debugger. You can find the corresponding function by searching the message in the AUCTeX source code. (`C-h m` in a TeX file to open the major mode description, click the hyperlink to `TeX-latex-mode`, click the source link to `latex.el`, then `M-x grep` with the word to search and `*.el`.)

For style hooks, the function that prints the message is `TeX-update-style` in `tex.el`. It runs functions collected from various places. It runs [style hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Style-Files.html#index-Style-hooks) registered for the file. You can find the list of style hooks that have run in the buffer-local variable `TeX-active-styles` (in reverse chronological order). In addition, it runs the hook functions in `TeX-update-style-hook`.

“Sorting environment” and “Removing duplicates” are from `TeX-auto-list-information` in `tex.el` which is called for things registered by `TeX-auto-add-type`. Environments are one of these things, there are also labels, bibliographies, symbols, etc. You can find the result of what it did in `LaTeX-environment-list`. More generally, `"Sorting foo"` operates on the content of a variable which is recorded in `TeX-auto-parser`: the variable's name is the third sublist element after `"foo`" (for example the sublist starting with `"environment" is`("environment" LaTeX-auto-environment LaTeX-add-environments LaTeX-environment-list LaTeX-environment-changed)`so what has been sorted and deduplicated is the content of the variable`LaTeX-environment-list`). If you want to know how the entries were ordered before the sorting, you'd have to instrument`TeX-auto-list-information`, but this information is pretty boring.